# ASP.NET Smart Card Image

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, smartcard, x509certificate2

I am trying to figure out if the image on a smart card is transmitted in the Certification in the request.

I have been able to get the Subject but what about the image

```
var localcert = Page.Request.ClientCertificate;
 X509Certificate2 certdata = new X509Certificate2(localcert.Certificate)
```

[image]

Comment: What image you are talking about? Certificate don't contain any defined fields for storing image inside it.

Comment: check the photo i put, there that is stored on the PIV

Comment: This is "regular" data object stored on smart-card in predefined position (as far as I remember PIV standard). You need direct access to smart card via Smart-card API or PKCS#11 interface.

Comment: Also look at the [Facial image specifications](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-76-2.pdf) Page 31.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a misunderstanding.

A PKI card contains a public and a private key (likely generated on the card), and this public key is contained in the certificate request.

The biometric pictures (portrait and fingerprints) contain a CBEFF signature block (see chapter 9.1 of Alexanders link), so the pictures are simply signed, but typically the party collecting these data has to sign them. So another key is used and there is no relation to the card holder and the corresponding key.